# Maximum number of memory segments that Notes can support has been exceeded

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am using Domino.dll to access a NSF file in C#.NET 2.0

I am using multiple thread to access 4 NSF files at a time, its working fine for small NSF files, but if i try to access large NSF files i get the **Out of Memory** Exception and **Maximum number of memory segments that Notes can support has been exceeded**.

This exception usually occurs when i access **NotesDocument** object from a large **NSFVIewFolder** in a while loop.

I am releasing the instance of the **NotesDocument** by using the Marshal.ReleaseComObject(NotesDocument); still it throws the same exception.

My goal is to access multiple NSF files at a time (MAX 4 NSF files at a time) for large NSF files (may be in GB).

Comment: Please do not indent your questions.

Comment: The guys that conceived and designed Lotus Notes were supposed to be incredibly smart, even gifted. So WTF happened?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the C# interface, but with Java, you need to explicitly call the recycle() method on the notes document before proceeding to the next document.  Failure to do this will mean the associated resources with the notes document will not be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is similar to [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21088734) problem. What version of Domino are you using to access the database ? You need to effectively destroy the object. I don't think that ReleaseComObject is effectively releasing the memory that the server would also use to provide the data to COM, thus running out of memory.

I suggest you try Java to do this as the memory management is much better supported than COM. 
[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/index.html) article and [this](http://lekkimworld.com/2006/04/09/java_in_notes_domino_explained_the_story_on_recycle.html) one should help write Java for Domino. [This](http://brunnur.stjr.is/help/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/13f19cf508c8d40b8525704a00418000?OpenDocument) simple example gives you an idea of how to get through a document collection.